# How to build a secure affiliate network

Tags: authentication, network, authorization

I'm going to build a demo affiliate network, which needs to be secured. Let say I have a web application called *Affiliate Network Manager* that manages all affiliates associated with my online book store.

Affiliate Network Manager provides an API that enables a publisher's web site (an affiliate site) to get the logo of the book store's web site, so it can display the book store logo on the publisher's web site.

**Let's assume the following scenario:** There is a publisher web site A, with *Unique ID* `123`. An end user visits the web site, clicks on the logo, is redirected to the online book store and buys a book.
The system gets the unique ID from the request and knows that this request comes from publisher A. Then, it remembers that the client visited the book store from publisher A. So, publisher A receives a commission based on the amount of the transaction.

**This works, but there is a security issue:** Assume we have another publisher B, with *Unique ID* `456`. Then an attacker from publisher B can capture a request from publisher A and change the unique ID to `456`. So, publisher B will receive the commission of publisher A.

How can I solve this security issue and make sure that the attacker can not change the unique ID when the request is transmitted? Or in other words: How can I do authentication in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understood you correctly, the affiliates have banner adds on their websites which look similar to this in HTML code:

```
<a href="http://example.com/store.php?UniqueID=123"><img src="http://example.com/banner.png"></a>
```

and your attack scenario is that when a visitor clicks on that banner, a MITM replaces the UniqueID in the visitors request with another.

To make significant revenue from exploiting an affiliate-network, one would have to be able to play MITM on a large number of connections. A man-in-the-middle attack is already quite difficult to perform when the attacker doesn't control any of the network infrastructure between the visitor and your server. So the scenario you proposed isn't very likely, unless one of the affiliates is also an ISP with lots of criminal energy.

But even when the attacker has full control over the connection, you can make it almost impossible to perform a MITM attack when you use TLS. So just ask your affiliates to link back to your bookstore using HTTPS-links instead of HTTP. When you have an online store you should be suppporting TLS anyway.

```
<a href="https://example.com/store.php?UniqueID=123"><img src="http://example.com/banner.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you basically need to do is:

1. Verify that a request is coming from an authenticated user, i.e. a user (or service) that's allowed to use your API; and
2. Ensure a request isn't altered while in transit, commonly known as a [Man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

You *could* install X.509 certificates on each publisher's web site and [use this to authenticate them over a HTTPS connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS#Use_as_access_control). This doesn't seem to be commonly done, however.

I recommend doing some research on the [OAuth 2.0 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth). It solves both problems, and software libraries exist for most web application frameworks.

Comment: Hi @Steven. Thanks for your sharing. But I just found that Amazon - a very big affiliate network do not do any secure authentication. Amazon put the publisher Unique ID directly to the url as a parameter. Do you have any reason why Amazon Affiliate Network works in that way?

Comment: Amazon uses [Hash-based message authentication code (HMAC-SHA1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-SHA1) to [authenticate REST service requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/LSAPI_Auth_REST.html), and an X.509 certificate to [authenticate SOAP requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/X509Certificates.html), like I explained in the answer. So it isn't _only_ the Unique ID that's sent; more information is transmitted so the server can verify the client's identity. All data is exchanged over HTTPS, solving problem #2.

Comment: @user44858: What's your point?

Comment: Hi Steven. I tried to work with Amazon affiliate, Amazon just create a iframe, and affiliate sites embed the iframe to their sites. No need to do any encryption, don't use any private key, no server side code. So I think Amazon don't actually do authentication based on HMAC-SHA1 for affiliate sites.